# Django model on already existing database

Tags: python, django

Initially Django model is created with suppose say 3 columns(name, age, sex) later the data base was dropped and created using sql dump the same table now have 4 columns (name, age, sex, phone) when I'm trying to add phone variable in the model I have the following error

`The field 'phone' clashes with the field 'phone' from model '...'`

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. What's in the file and does its database structure match your Django models? Are you importing into the same database as Django is configured to use?

Comment: It was because of database structures it was resolved but I have new issue now, kindly go through it. @solarissmoke